# Runtime Error on connecting Oracle 10g using Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I can run my program successfully in the development machine, however, I found that the users encountered the runtime error when starting to connect oracle DB. Indeed, I added the references but the debugger said that "the provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client",

Development Environment
- C# WinForm
- .Net Framework 4.5
- Oracle 10g Database

please help! Thanks!

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at TradeImport.Classes.Adapters.PLSqlAdapter.getConnection()
   at TradeImport.ImportBond5YEVForm.btnConnect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Importer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/ccho/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/ERG0T4E0.6M4/LQHVKBQJ.17D/etci..tion_93b81ee98636ebca_0001.0000_9ccdf984ecfcdfd0/Importer.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Oracle.DataAccess
    Assembly Version: 1.102.2.20
    Win32 Version: 1.102.2.20
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Oracle.DataAccess/1.102.2.20__89b483f429c47342/Oracle.DataAccess.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This suggests a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch.  Which version (32-bit/64-bit) of the Oracle client is on the machine running the application?  Are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in your app?

Comment: Im using 32bit oracle client, but I can run the program successfully

Comment: So that suggests you might be using the 32-bit `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.  What about the Oracle client on the other computers you're trying to run your program on?

Comment: Thanks! I just installed the oracle client 12c and referenced ManagedDataAccess.dll. Then, the problem is fixed

Comment: Glad to hear you got the problem fixed.  Would it be possible to write your comment up as an answer?  That should make the solution more obvious to others who have the same problem as you and come across this question.

Comment: That's no problem! I just installed oracle client 12c, then re-referencing the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll in the <oracle_home>\odp.net\managed\common\ instead of Oracle.DataAccess.dll